# Read CSV and create new CSV with only specified columns and subset or rows based on specific values

Tags: pandas, csv, python-import, export-to-csv, python-3.8

I have a CSV file with 5 columns:

```
Student Id, Course Id, Student Name, Course Name, GPA
12,112 , John,Math, 3.7
11,111 , Mohammed,Astronomy, 3.89
10,100 , Peter,Java Programming, 3.5
9,99 , Lisa,Cooking, 4.0
```

Using Python 3.8 I need to read that file and create a new CSV file with fewer columns eliminating all leading and trailing spaces:

(Student Name, Course Name and GPA),

but only where the Name field contains certain values (eg: 'John', 'Lisa')

And if there are nor records with corresponding Names, then DO NOT CREATE an output file and print a message
(eg.: 'No Student name(s) found in the database')

I'm using the following code to create new CSV file with required columns, but I'm not sure how to  select only subset of records for my new (output) CSV file.

```
import csv

with open('My_Source_file.csv') as infile, open('My_Ouput_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    csv.writer(outfile).writerows((row[3], row[4], row[5]) for row in csv.reader(infile))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

dta = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
# removing the white space from column names:
dta.columns = dta.columns.str.strip() 

# removing the tailing white space from all records in all columns:

for col in dta.columns:
    # checking if column is string:
    if dta[col].dtype == object:
        dta[col] = dta[col].str.strip()

selection_list = ['John', 'Lisa']
dta = dta[dta['Student Name'].isin(selection_list)]
    
if len(dta) != 0:
    # pass your selected column as a list like this:
    selected_columns = ["Student Id","Course Id","Student Name"]
    dta[selected_columns].to_csv('My_Ouput_file.csv', index=False)

else:
    print('No Student name(s) found in the database')
```

output:

```
   Student Id Course Id   Student Name 
0  12         112         John         
3  9          99          Lisa
```

This script gets the names (or your variables of interest) in `selection_list` and selects rows where selected column (`Student Name`) has them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help @Babak Fi Foo, would you mind to amend your code to trim leading and trailing spaces? That was one of my requirements which I forgot to mention.

Comment: @enigma6205 White space is fixed.

Comment: Also, @Babak Fi Foo, I just realized that we missed a part which would filter out columns. As I mentioned in my question I wanted to return only some columns, not all. Could you check on this? It used to work with my old code (refer to the question). But how do we integrate it your code?

Comment: Additionally to columns question I've also checked whites and the output file still contains trailing and leading spaces...

Comment: @enigma6205 all added.

Comment: There is an error @Bobak Fi Foo : "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!" Seems like it occurs somewhere here: dta[col] = dta[col].str.strip()

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to add a string checking line. now it should work fine with the sample

Comment: Awesome. It worked. How exactly this "if dta[col].dtype == object" converts the columns to string?

Comment: It just checks if the column is string. Numbers' white space is removed automatically, but string ones require extra work.